# Is a Python list a singly or doubly linked list?

Tags: python, list, complexity-theory, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm wondering what the order of complexity for a Python v2.7 list being built up using append() is?  Is a Python list doubly linked and thus it is constant complexity or is it singly linked and thus linear complexity?  If it is singly linked, how can I in linear time build up a list from an iteration that provides the values of the list in the order of from beginning to end?

For example:

```
def holes_between(intervals):
  # Compute the holes between the intervals, for example:
  #     given the table: ([ 8,  9] [14, 18] [19, 20] [23, 32] [34, 49])
  #   compute the holes: ([10, 13] [21, 22] [33, 33])
  prec = intervals[0][1] + 1 # Bootstrap the iteration
  holes = []
  for low, high in intervals[1:]:
    if prec <= low - 1:
      holes.append((prec, low - 1))
    prec = high + 1
  return holes
```

Comment: It's not a linked list at all. It's essentially what is formally called a dynamic array. Where'd you get the idea that it's a linked list?

Comment: @delnan Sort of. Unlike in certain other languages, it isn't static, otherwise `append` wouldn't work at all. It's closer to Java's ArrayLists, and similar constructs in other languages. See [Dynamic Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array). Edit: Sorry, I didn't see the "dynamic" at first. You're right, of course.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac That's why I edited it to say "dynamic array" almost immediately after posting ;-)

Comment: I think people get the impression that Python's lists are linked because that's how they are in Scheme, Lisp, Haskell, ML, Go, F#, OCaml, Clojure, Scala, and many other languages. In this regard Python does not follow the principle of least surprise, and violates basic assumptions of linked lists regarding order statistics (i.e. big-O notation). This makes Python more difficult to teach, as lists and tuples are not orthogonal data structures.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The time complexity for python `list.append()` is O(1). See the [Time Complexity list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the Python Wiki.

Internally, python lists are vectors of pointers:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

The `ob_item` vector is resized as needed with overallocation to give an amortized O(1) cost for appends:

```
/* This over-allocates proportional to the list size, making room
 * for additional growth.  The over-allocation is mild, but is
 * enough to give linear-time amortized behavior over a long
 * sequence of appends() in the presence of a poorly-performing
 * system realloc().
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
 */
new_allocated = (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
```

This makes Python lists [dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Comment: The link to the Time Complexity list you shared is of great help. Thank you.